# Delay binding of an expander until it is expanded

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a window that is databound to a ViewModel. The ViewModel has many properties, some of which are expensive to evaluate and are not always needed by the user.

What I would like to do is have these properties databound to controls contained in different unexpanded expanders. When the expander is expanded by the user I would like the controls to bind and the properties to be evaluated. If the user does not expand the expander, the properties should not be evaluated, and the cost not incurred.

I could certainly do this using events from the expander but I'm trying to find a nice MVVM way of doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  It means "no application logic in codebehind."  You can create a custom user control which controls when the DataContext of a child Expander is set, or you can extend the Expander and do this in code.

Comment: I agree, and I don't want to get religious about it. It's just this solution will be used in serveral places and I'd like as much code in the VM as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
<Expander Header="Diagnostics" IsExpanded="False">
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Style.Triggers>                                    
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Diagnostics}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue}" />
</Expander>
```

If you just want the expanded binding to be the datacontext of the parent window, then presumably this would work in the trigger:

```
<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext}" />
```

Comment: this solution is going the right direction, but the problem is even though you accomplish the binding deferral, the trigger will null the binding when expander is collapsed. 2 problems with that, you miss on all your property changed (if you need them), second you have to load your expensive datacontext again.

Comment: Good point, although maybe the user wants to re-detatch the datacontext if the user collapses it again, so that there aren't expensive UI operations on PropertyChanged events for the would-be-bound properties.

Comment: Hey sorry again, you totally right on IsAsync="True", and since it requires a person to know how to implement that, now I see why you short-circuited your answer with Thread.Sleep

Comment: I tried something similar but it didn't work because I was setting the DataContent to null on the control, not in the style. Don't know why that makes a difference, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: The reason it didn't work that way is that if you set a property on an element, and it's style also sets that property, the style setter is ignored because the other one takes precedence. See [MSDN's Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

@Alain's suggestion looks interesting.

In addition, since your properties are expensive to evaluate, you should also look at async bindings and priority bindings.

An async example:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=Description, IsAsync="True"}/>
```

Setting IsAsync=True will prevent binding evaluation from blocking the UI thread.

You can also use priority binding, which is a form of multi-binding:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <Samples:PriorityBindingViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <PriorityBinding>
                <Binding Path="ExpensiveProperty" Mode="OneWay" IsAsync="True"/>
                <Binding Path="LessExpensiveProperty" Mode="OneWay" IsAsync="True"/>
                <Binding Path="LeastExpensiveProperty" Mode="OneWay" IsAsync="True"/>
            </PriorityBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Bindings are evaluated with priority from top to bottom.  This allows you to put say a 'loading ...' message in the lowest priority binding (LeastExpensiveProperty) while the high priority but slower bindings are being evaluated.

```
public class PriorityBindingViewModel
{
    private string _expensiveProperty;

    private string _lessExpensiveProperty;

    public PriorityBindingViewModel()
    {
        ExpensiveProperty = "Loaded";
        LessExpensiveProperty = "Still loading";
        LeastExpensiveProperty = "Loading";
    }

    public string ExpensiveProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Thread.Sleep is in place of an 'expensive' operation.
            // Just in case anyone doesn't realize.
            Thread.Sleep(8000);  
            return _expensiveProperty;
        }
        private set { _expensiveProperty = value; }
    }

    public string LessExpensiveProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Same here.
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return _lessExpensiveProperty;
        }
        private set { _lessExpensiveProperty = value; }
    }

    public string LeastExpensiveProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep(..) is a code smell of a poorly designed solution on so many levels, here is completely non-deterministic state of resolving a property

Comment: Oh, man, don't take things personally, code/notes are for the common good. My mates pointed out a few things this morning with my code -> and I totally deserved it, as long as it can be better, i am all for it. I didn't down your answer or anything, just pointed out something for the person that might user your code. take it easy, man

Comment: I really don't think the Thread.Sleep comment was necessary either. I would have thought that was obvious to anyone who actually read the solution description before the code sample. Anyways, well hashed out proposed solution Phil.

Comment: Hey sorry again, you totally right on IsAsync="True", and since it requires a person to know how to implement that, now I see why you short-circuited your answer with Thread.Sleep

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about async binding - I've used them elsewhere but in this case I want an animation playing while the data is loading so the VM is doing the work async.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
   <....
</Expander>

in .cs:

private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var expander = (Expander)sender;

    if(expander.DataContext == null)
    expander.DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```